# Python - parse graphql, add something, then back to the query string

Tags: python, graphql

I'm trying to use python to parse a graphql query, alter it, and turn it back into a string query that I can pass to the graphql server.

Specifically, I'm trying to ensure that a query will always have the `pageInfo` paging information, so if I'm executing a query, I will always be able to automatically page through the results, even if a user might forget that stanza in their actual query.

It seems surprisingly difficult to parse a graphql query into something useful, and then be able to go from the parsed data representation back to the query string. Is there a library that google isn't able to turn up for me?

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [core library](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core) includes a `parse` function for parsing strings into AST and a `print_ast` function for converting the AST back to a string.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks! I somehow overlooked `print_ast` - you don't happen to have any examples of how to edit this ast, do you? Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced a similar problem. For future reference: the way you edit the AST is by creating a visitor class that will enter the tree and modify it to your liking. It's described in the documentation [here](https://graphql-core-3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/language.html#visitor). For example, in order to remove field named `attributes` I used following code:

```python
from graphql import parse, print_ast
from graphql.language.visitor import visit, Visitor, REMOVE, IDLE

class RemoveAttributesVisitor(Visitor):
    def enter_field(self, node, key, parent, path, ancestors):
        if node.name.value == "attributes":
            return REMOVE
        return IDLE

ast = parse(PRODUCT_QUERY)
new_ast = visit(ast, RemoveAttributesVisitor())
updated_query = print_ast(new_ast)
```